# Windows Admin Center: is login to web-UI from other machines possible?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-server-2019

I found that even after opening firewall ports and accepting the SSL cert, I get this when trying to login to Windows Admin Center from any other machine on my domain:

*"You are not authorized to view this page. If you recently updated Windows Admin Center, you may need to restart your browser, and then refresh the page."*

Checking these old SW post here, there was no solution/best-answer listed:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2205475-windows-admin-center-1904
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2340792-window-admin-center-unable-to-sso-login?started_from=...

I'm trying the following

1. Version 2110 (I'm using Build 1.3.2111.01001)
2. Using a Domain Admin session in Windows (for Kerberos), even using
   the *same* Domain user which works locally on the machine which is
   hosting the app.
3. Running the browser as admin (really?) Exporting the SSL cert ->
   importing it and storing it in Trusted Root CA on the client machine.
4. Completely disabled Windows firewall on the PC hosting the WAC web app.
5. Brand new install of WAC on a different machine, this one on Win11 instead of Win10....exact same issue.

I'm unsure exactly how the app is using the SSL certificate for authentication - perhaps this is the issue?

...but nothing works? Any ideas?

Screenshot of the issue:
[image: WAC-login-issue-from-other-machine]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?  This has nothing to do with the permissions of the browser. In other words, running it as an administrator, wouldn't; have worked.  This is a straight configuration problem.

Comment: Yes, done. Thanks

Comment: So the Windows Admin Center service must be installed to run with a local Administrator.  You should be able to view the properties of the service to identify which account is being used. This error is indicating your user doesn’t have the permissions to view the page. [Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2319856-windows-admin-center-changed-local-account-password-and-wac-stops-working) seems to be a relevant page. I also would like to see if https://localhost:6516/ causes the same error

Comment: Thanks. There is no issue accessing the site via https://localhost:6516 on the machine that is hosting the web-app. I think it could be a GP issue.

Comment: If it works on local host that actually means it’s probably the certificate. Based on my quick research WAC isn’t nor designed to be a server. Did this work flow ever?

Comment: Apparently it is something environmental to my network. I tried in a different lab that I have access to and it is prompting me for a UN & PW.....then login from another machine works as expected. 

The WAC setups I've done in my network are not doing this. Perhaps a Group Policy issue....?

Comment: @Ramhound, WAC absolutely *is* intended to be used as a web-server. Check the docs here about setting up as a Gateway Server: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/plan/installation-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've inadvertently answered my own question: if WAC is running on a Win10/Win11 (client type OS) it can only be configured as a **Local Client**:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/plan/installation-options

To have WAC accessible from any machine on the network it must be installed on **Windows Server** 2016 or 2019.